# how manys ways are there if the order is taken into account?

Tags: probability, statistics

Three candidates are selected from a certain number of interviewess. if the order is not taken into account, the number of ways the candidates can be chosen is 35. how manys ways are there if the order is taken into account?
here is where i get stuck"
3 candidates
35=(n p r)/(n-r)!r!
n p3 =35(n-3)!3!

i guess that the n is 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ denote total number interviewess. So 3 of them can be chosen without order in $\frac {n!}{((n-3)!)(3!)}=35-----(1)$ ways. We have to find out $\frac {n!}{(n-3)!}$.

Putting in (1), we get that $\frac {n!}{(n-3)!}=(3!)35=6*35=210.$

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the order is *not* taken into account can be "repaired" by taking it into account afterwards. This comes to multiplying by $3!=6$ wich is simply the number of possible orders for the $3$ candidates.

So the answer is $6\times35=210$.

Your guess that $n=7$ is correct, but for solution of this problem it is not really needed to know $n$.